# How to change the column names and make a data frame of columns in the dataset

Tags: r

I am building a function to change the column names of 3 columns and make a new data frame with 3 column. The file name is noaaFilename, and Date, HrMn, and Slp were earlier column names and new names I want as Date, Time, AtmosPressure.

```
  names(noaaFilename)[names(noaaFilename) == "Date"] <- "Date"
  names(noaaFilename)[names(noaaFilename) == "HrMn"] <- "Time"
  names(noaaFilename)[names(noaaFilename) == "Slp"] <- "AtmosPressure"

  noaaData <- subset(noaaFilename, select = c(Date, Time, AtmosPressure))
```

Comment: Yo may need to provide some example data for your example to run for others. Questions should be reproducible. Meaning anyone seeing the code should have all they need given. Try providing several lines of noaafilename.

Answer (score 0):

```
noaaData <- subset(noaaFilename, select = c(Date, HrMn, Slp))

names(noaaData) <- c("Date", "Time", "AtmosPressure")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysubset <- function(df, oldnames, newnames){
  if(length(oldnames)!=length(newnames)){
    stop("oldnames and newnames are not the same length")
  }
  if(!all(oldnames%in%colnames(df)){
    stop("Not all of oldnames match column names of df")
  }
  df <- df[,oldnames, drop = F]
  colnames(df) <- newnames
  return(df)
}
```

An example with the iris data set.

```
head(iris)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
tmp <- mysubset(iris,
                oldnames = c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Species"),
                newnames = c("Date","Time","AtmosPressure"))
head(tmp)
#  Date Time AtmosPressure
#1  5.1  3.5        setosa
#2  4.9  3.0        setosa
#3  4.7  3.2        setosa
#4  4.6  3.1        setosa
#5  5.0  3.6        setosa
#6  5.4  3.9        setosa
```

Writing the function like this makes it so you don't only need to specify 3 columns.